# Binding array + one object to Dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I have an array of type Person, which contains string objects: FirstName, LastName, login.

I have this bound to a dropdownlist.

Now along with this array, I also want to display one more item called "Desk". How can i do that?

My current code is:

```
Person[] traders = GetTraders();
ddl_trader.Items.Clear();
ddl_trader.DataSource = traders;
ddl_trader.DataTextField = "LastName";
ddl_trader.DataValueField = "Login";
ddl_trader.DataBind();
```

I also want that one extra item I'm adding to be the default selected item.

Comment: What is "Desk" ? A property of Person ? An independent object with a link to Person ?

Comment: An independent string. Its not of type Person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `AppendDataBoundItems` property to `true` (it's `false` by default), add your item manually, then do the databinding process to add the remaining items. `AppendDataBoundItems` determines if the list is cleared during databinding or not.

```
ddl_trader.Items.Clear();
ddl_trader.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
ddl_trader.Items.Add("Desk");
ddl_trader.DataTextField = "LastName";
ddl_trader.DataValueField = "Login";
ddl_trader.DataSource = traders;
ddl_trader.DataBind();
```

if you need to add the new item after the list has been bound, you can do

```
ddl_trader.Items.Insert(0, "Desk");
```

this does not require setting `AppendDataBoundItems` to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

One such method is to load the result of `GetTraders()` into a `List<Person>`. You can then add one or many new `Person` objects to the list before binding it to your dropdown.

```
List<Person> traders = new List<Person>(GetTraders());
traders.Add(new Person() { LastName = "Foo", Login = "Bar" });
ddl_trader.DataSource = traders;
```

You could also define an additional array and concatenate that to the result instead of creating a combined collection. (Note: this would be two distinct arrays treated as a single sequence, however the backing arrays would still be seperate).

```
Person[] traders = GetTraders();
Person[] moreTraders = new Person[] { new Person() { LastName = "Foo", Login = "Bar" } };
ddl_trader.DataSource = traders.Concat(moreTraders);
```

Comment: I was wondeing if it could be done without adding it to the list. Since, it is really just a string "Desk" and doesn't need a FirstName, Lastname etc.

Comment: Gotcha. If I can't figure out a way to do it without creating another array of Person class, I'll use your second method.

Comment: For some reason, traders.Concat returns an error. Is there some assembly or reference I need to use Concat?

Comment: @xbonez, It's an extension method of `IEnumerable<T>` from .NET 3.5+, C# 3.0+. If you are on a compatible platform (think: Visual Studio 2008 or 2010), you'd need a reference to System.Core.dll and a `using System.Linq;` statement in your code-behind. If you are on a prior version of .NET, try the first approach (VS 2005+, `using System.Collections.Generic;`).